# simplify linq expression in for each loop

Tags: vb.net, expression, simplify

i want to remove or set an item equal to nothing in a collection or list
the following code works but is there a simplier expression

```
For Each i In response.Report.Arrestee
            i.ArresteeArmedWithCode = Nothing
        Next
```

Comment: Related to the answer below, there's nothing stopping you from writing your own `ForEach` extension method on `IEnumerable(Of T)` (that is, after all, exactly what Linq itself is, a set of extension methods on `IEnumerable(Of T)`).  That having been said, you're unlikely to gain significantly in clarity by doing so, it will usually be better to just spell out the loop explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ isn't supposed to have side effects, so don't try and create LINQ expressions that set values.

If `Arrestee` is a `List<T>` you can do `Arrestee.ForEach(Function(a) a.ArresteeArmedWithCode = Nothing)` (ForEach is a List thing, not a LINQ thing) but it's relatively opinionated as to whether that's simpler. It's *fewer lines* but brevity does not always lead to clarity